# android honeycomb - how to make options menu item look disabled?

Tags: android, user-interface, menu, menuitem, options-menu

I am trying to disable one of the options menu items using the foll code:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
     menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_id).setEnabled(false);
     return true;
}
```

However after the method is executed, disabled item looks just like the rest (enabled) of the menu.

Is it possible to make it look disabled (grayed out or something)? How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using icon resources that are built in to Android, or did you make custom icons?

Comment: It's a custom text-only menu inflated from XML in run-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Themes? Check out this post: [How to change the Text color of Menu item in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android)

Once you set up a Theme, you may find this helpful for finding what values can be set: [Themes XML](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=d585d9e11f6369352745cb23bbd49a257604e944;hb=HEAD)