# Can't change the text color with Android Action Bar drop-down navigation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm using Drop-down Navigation with my Action bar, and I can't get a sensible color for the corresponding text when using a dark action bar.  The action bar itself is a dark grey, and the text color is black, so it's very hard to read.

I followed the basic instructions on the [Action Bar developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) so my code is simply

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO
        return false;
    }
};
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);        
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, navigationListener);
```

and my styles.xml was simply

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

I *think* that should have given me something sensible, but as the following image shows, it comes out as black text on a dark grey background so it's no good.

[image: Image of menu with black text on a dark grey background]

I've tried playing around with the styles.xml file to try and solve the problem.  My best attempt was the following

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/myActionDropDownStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myActionDropDownStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@color/LightCyan</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">    
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myActionBar.titleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myActionBar.titleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Orange</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: Best attempt at making the items readable in the navigation dropdown]

which was (1) able to change the text color of the app title to Orange, (2) able to change the background color of the selected navigation item in the action bar to a light blue, (3) able to change the background color of the dropdown so that at least the black text is shown against a light background. However nothing I do changes the text color itself, either for the selected item shown in the action bar, or for the items shown in the dropdown.  My best attempt also looks horrible :-(!

All I want is a dark action bar with a sensible text color for the selected item shown in the action bar, which should be the same text color used when an item is being selected, and with the background color for the dropdown when an item is being selected being the same color as the action bar.  But I can't work out how to do it, can anyone help?

FYI, I'm using Eclipse with an adt-bundle that I downloaded very recently (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219).  When I search for solutions, I find a lot about the Sherlock action bar, however the styles for Sherlock weren't included in that adt-bundle.  In any case, surely what I want should be possible with the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar that I'm using?

Comment: refer this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've worked out that I can alter the colors for the drop-down Navigation in code, by creating my own subclass of ArrayAdapter as follows:

```
public class myArrayAdaptor<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    public myArrayAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public static myArrayAdaptor<CharSequence> createFromResource(Context context, int textArrayResId, int textViewResId) {
        CharSequence[] strings = context.getResources().getTextArray(textArrayResId);
        return new myArrayAdaptor<CharSequence>(context, textViewResId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return SetColourWhite(super.getView(position, convertView, parent));
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return SetColourWhite(super.getView(position, convertView, parent));
    }

    private View SetColourWhite(View v) {
        if (v instanceof TextView) ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.rgb(0xff, 0xff, 0xff)); // white
        return v;
    }
}
```

Then with the simple styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

I can substitute the class myArrayAdaptor

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

and the text color will always be white.  But isn't there a simpler way of doing this using settings in the styles.xml file?

Comment: You can use [`ContextThemeWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html): `SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo), R.array...., android.R.layout....);`

Comment: Or [`ActionBar.getThemedContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#getThemedContext()) for _API 14+_. I found the answer [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25624#c1).

Comment: @SaDec, thanks, if I have to revisit this bit of my app I'll look into your suggestions :-).

Comment: @SaDec 'ActionBar.getThemedContext()' is so useful once I read your comment ! You should write an answer on it for future readers.

Comment: omg more then day searching work working solution on same problem and here is hidden answer - ActionBar.getThemedContext(). Thank you Sa Dec very much

Comment: I have a problem with using ActionBar.getThemedContext(). The text shown when not selecting an item is fine, but if I click the spinner, the list given now is of bad color...light gray with white text. Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 28):

Please forgive my necromancy but this really bugged me today and the solution is actually quite quick and requires no custom adapters or styling.

If you change the context in the SpinnerAdapter's constructor to use getActionBar().getThemedContext() rather than this it will show light text on a dark background that will match the Action Bar's style.

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion :-).  The project that I needed this answer for is now dormant, but I'll look at your suggestion if it the project is ever revived.

Comment: Worked! Thanx a lot. I was struggling with the themes created from Theme-Generator (http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to find out how to change the text color from black to white.

Comment: This is an awesome find! This saved me after hours of hair-pulling!

Comment: You can't imagine how many hours i wasted around this problem. Finally an elegant solution, thank you! PS: in my case i have to use getSupportActionBar() intead of getActionBar().

Comment: P.S There is no necromancy in knowledge gathering (and anywhere). Please, forget about this term. There was no such term as "necro" until masses get access to internet and bring our usual cogitative patterns. 
Edit: Internet is the freedom - do what you want - if something looks weird, then tools, which provide services should be fixed. e.g. unsubscribe, autoclose old post, etc.

Comment: Well put. I used the term originally because SO awarded me a "Necromancer" badge when I answered this question.

Answer (score 4):

Java code

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.actions,R.layout.dropdown_textcolor);

// OnNavigationListener
OnNavigationListener callback = new OnNavigationListener() {

    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actions); 
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {

        // Do stuff when navigation item is selected
        Log.d("NavigationItemSelected", items[position]); // Debug
        return true;
    }

};


ActionBar actions = getSupportActionBar();
actions.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actions.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

actions.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, callback);
```

Xml dropdown_textcolor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your styles.xml that will change the color of your hidden action menu text:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppCompat.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuTextAppearance</item>    
</style>

<style name="MenuTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is clear and sensible. I placed this into my `values-night/themes.xml` and it just worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>

        <item name="android:itemBackground">#991005</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarSize">40dp</item>

        <item name="android:divider">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>

        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>



    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat support library .. this might help you..

```
<style name="MyActionBar3" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/ActionBarBackground</item>         
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarDropDownStyle" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">#00FF00</item>        
    <item name="android:divider">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>     
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#FF0000</item>        
</style>
```