# How can I change the color of the textView android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item?

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, android-styles

I'm creating a SpinnerAdapter using the built in resource ID android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

but the textView which that resource ID creates has textColor Black and I need a different color.  What's the best way of changing the color but keeping everything else the same?

When I try and create my own textView layout resource in an xml file, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    />
```

then it doesn't behave in the same way as android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item because e.g. the padding is different.  So

1. Is there a way of creating my own layout resource in an xml file which inherits everything from android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item and allows me to override the textColor?
2. Or is the complete definition of android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item available somewhere?
3. Or perhaps there's an even easier way somehow?

This question relates to another question that I've asked today ([Can't change the text color with Android Action Bar drop-down navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948026/cant-change-the-text-color-with-android-action-bar-drop-down-navigation/15955298#15955298)).  I've realised that one answer to that question (and hence this question) is to create my own `ArrayAdapter` class which inherits from `ArrayAdapter<T>` so that I can always set the color in code whenever the ArrayAdapter gets used (see my answer to that question).  But that seems like a very cumbersome solution :-|.

Changing a text color shouldn't be a hard task!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way of creating my own layout resource in an xml file which inherits everything from android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item and allows me to override the textColor?

No, but you can cut & paste your favorite version of `simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` to a new file then simply change the text color.

> Or is the complete definition of android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item available somewhere?

Yes, but there are many different versions.  Which API do you like?  Also you might have a copy on your hard drive already, check `<android-sdk>/platforms/android-xx/data/res/layout/` (where `xx` is a particular API.)

---

As an alternate approach you can create a custom Adapter and change the text color after you inflate each row, but the method above will be slightly faster since it doesn't involve any run time changes.

Comment: thx vm :-).  In fact I'd already found your alternate approach, but now you've told me where to look for the xml defintions I'll probably switch to that.

Comment: +1 for your line of thinking...I added to your solution since this won't work right away without changes.

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Sam's solution, you will need to modify the file in very specific ways to override Android's styles.

After you copy the `simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` from the sdk folder into the correct layout folder you are working with, you will see this code:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

In order to change the background of the TextView and avoid this error:

> .../res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml:20: error: Error: Attribute is not public. (at 'layout_height' with value '?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight').

your code will need to look like this:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
style="@style/SpinnerTextViewItem"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

The other main change that needs to be made is to create your own style.  You probably have a styles.xml file, so add a new style similar to this:

```
<style name="SpinnerTextViewItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView" >
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Assuming you have something in your colors.xml file, you can set the color via "@color/green" or whatever color you choose (of course you can use @android:color/...) not to mention all the other items you can add to change the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Without using custom adapter it is impossible to change the color of

```
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
```

Better create a custom adapter and then you can change the color, testSixe, textStyle, etc.

Comment: well, if you do what Sam says to do, then you are able to edit simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml...