# Android actionBar navigation mode list style

Tags: android

[image]

i selected

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

now i want to change the style of the spinner in the action bar,

using style sheet if i apply the background to the spinner it is applying to the spinner which is define by me (as shown in the fig), but the styles are not applying to the default action bar spinner,

in the below figure the first one is action bar spinner and second one is defined by me

and my style sheet is

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" >

    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/StandardSpinner</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/StandardSpinnerItem</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StandardSpinner" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/text_box</item>
    </style>
```

How to apply style for default action bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems trying to change the text colour and background colour of the spinner in the action bar.  See [How can I change the color of the textView android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955804/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-textview-android-r-layout-simple-spinner-dropd).  I ended up creating my own custom adaptor, see my code in [Can't change the text color with Android Action Bar drop-down navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948026/cant-change-the-text-color-with-android-action-bar-drop-down-navigation).  That may be your best solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed this by creating a ContextThemeWrapper with dark Holo theme and passing it as a Context to the adapter:

```
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
ArrayAdapter<Timetable> timetableAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Timetable>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1, timetables);
```