# Android simple spinner item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

this question relates to this one: [android.R.simple_spinner_item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955804/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-textview-android-r-layout-simple-spinner-dropd/15955877#15955877)

Since I can't comment because of low reputation, I have an additional question:

If I copy&paste the android.R.simple_spinner_item layout, I get an error on

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
```

saying "error: Error: Attribute is not public. (at 'layout_height' with value '?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight')."

I just added `android:gravity="right"` to get the spinner_item alignment to the right side.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. You Cannot use `dropdownListPreferredItemHeight` as its not public.

Answer (score 42):

Seems to work for me if you don't prefix it with android, like so:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@android:id/text1"
             style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
             android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How does it not answer the question? It literally directly answers the question....

Comment: @DanielWilson `android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"` is marked as private in appcompat-v7

Answer (score 4):

then you will have to design it.

layout/my_spinner_textview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

and this is how i set the adapter

```
 private String[] state= {"Andra Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Haryana","Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jharkhand","Karnataka", "Kerala","Tamil Nadu"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.my_spinner_textview, state);
        adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);

    }
```

Comment: I know, but this will also set the alignment to left. I want the default view with alignment right.

Comment: sorry I meant, this will wrap the content so the listitem is smalller than the `dropdownListPreferredItemHeight`.
If I know how high that would be, I could set the heigt... not a beautiful solution though

Comment: @Zuop It's `64dip`.

Answer (score 4):

This resource is private, so only the library which that attribute comes from can use it. So you need to get the size of this attribute and create it within your app. From the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/50fe5ec/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml

we can see at lines 50 and/or 84 the attribute there.
So in your dimens.xml file you can write:

`<dimen name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">64dip</dimen>`

and then reference it like you would a normal resource:

`android:layout_height="@dimen/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"`

Answer (score 2):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

> Create a custom layout with these attributes. You might want to theme it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the android resources (themes or attributes) that are defined as public by System.

As attr `"?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"` is not public, you cannot use that.

Instead, you can use

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

for Spinner item layout.

Another workaround may be of copying the resources from SDK to your project and then use them in your project.

Comment: I already tried "wrap content" but this will minimize the item height radically so its to small. I juut want to stay with the default size.

Comment: Wow, everyone keeps giving the same terrible suggestion, which removes the space between each item. Why would anybody be content with that?