# how to give color to the application title string in android

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I want to give the rgb color to the application title string in my application 
string in the resource file I have declared like this,

```
<string name="app_name">MyApplication</string>
```

and used it to set the title in manifest file like this,

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I want to give different color to **My** and **Application** words,
rgb(201,89,51) for My and rgb(74,137,174) respectively

How can I do this?

Comment: what? you cannot do that

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948026/cant-change-the-text-color-with-android-action-bar-drop-down-navigation) might help you. **OR** the best and easy way to get it is by using a TextView on top with the colored text ( using Html.fromHtml) and using FullScreenActivity.

Comment: And [this](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>My</font><font color='#ff00ff'>Application</font>"));
```

if you are using appcompact :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>My</font><font color='#ff00ff'>Application</font>"));
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot. Come to know about using HTML in android code, used for first time

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Html.fromHtml(String s)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) ? output gives you styled by HTML text. An example:

```
String styledText=Html.fromHtml("<font color="#123456">My</font> <font color="#654321">App</font>");
```

and then set:

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.setTitle(styledText);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(styledText);
//getActionBar().setTitle(styledText);
```