# how to change actionbar's menu item text color in material design

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm trying to update my notepad app to use Material Design, even on older devices.

What i did so far:

1. add library appcompat_v7 to my project, to support Material Design on older devices
2. modify theme in AndroidManifest, adding `android:theme="@style/Theme.NoteItTheme"` to `<application ... ></application>` attributes
3. creating the theme in /res/values/themes.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <style name="Theme.NoteItTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
       <!-- <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item> --> 

       <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/ui</item>

       <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
   </style>
   ```

**The problem:**

As you can better see here:

[image: the problem]

when i expand the actionbar's menu, text color and background color are very similar.
I hadn't this problem before, how do i change just the items text color?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">yourColor</item>
```

Above code changes the text color of the menu action items for API >= v21.

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
```

Above is the code for API < v21

Some tutorials:

[Changing toolbar's text color and overflow icon color](http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/)

[Appcompat v21 Pre-Lollipop devices](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=F93OVIv3C4GkULjwgNAF&url=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html%3Fm%3D1&ved=0CCcQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNHsqPPBTDdJhCTY6fsUf601KBes0g&sig2=q8QFDvXNq8H8M7monLAiag)

Comment: How do i implement these properties based on API level?

Comment: You can create a style file for each api level. Just copy and paste the styles files in the same folder and in the dialog add -v19 (for example)

Comment: Doesn't work. Changing 'android:textColorPrimary' changes the item text color, but this also changes the actionbar title text color.

Comment: You should take a look this post https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=F93OVIv3C4GkULjwgNAF&url=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html%3Fm%3D1&ved=0CCcQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNHsqPPBTDdJhCTY6fsUf601KBes0g&sig2=q8QFDvXNq8H8M7monLAiag

Comment: And this: http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/

Comment: You mean i should switch to using a ToolBar?

Comment: Yes, you should switch. You can solve your problem following that two posts if you use toolbar.

Comment: Ok, i'll accept as answer because you provided couple of nice tutorials, but please add 'read comments' to answer.

Comment: and next step we have to do is to this style in our toolbar for theme and popuptheme attributes

Answer (score 9):

Below worked for me

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">yourColor</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">yourColor</item>
```

Comment: this answer is correct. the above anwer doesnot work for api level less then 21

Comment: That only works for items in the toolbar, but it doesn't work for the menu icon. which one could I use for that

Comment: 1 for what I was looking for, I only needed to to change colour of toolbar items

Answer (score 1):

**Below work for me fine.**

```
<item name="android:textColor">your color</item>
```