# How to hide a navigation drawer menu item programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I want to hide a menu item in navigation drawer menu and show it depending on the type of the user that is using the application according to code below menu item is returning null:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    MenuItem target = (MenuItem)drawer.findViewById(R.id.nav_target);

    target.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `menu.findItem(R.id.nav_target)`?

Comment: @droid8421 no I didn't because I need to declare menu.

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/29239511/3549047

Comment: As I said i want to hide navigation drawer menu item and not option menu item.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Fixed it by creating a menu and using

```
menu.findItem(R.id.nav_target)
```

as @droid8421 suggested.

Fixed Code:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Menu menu =navigationView.getMenu();

MenuItem target = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_target);

target.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when developing an application that has two productFlavours (Free & Premium)

What I did to show the BuyProVersion Menu item in the Free Version and disable it in the Premium Version was:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem buyPro = 
menu.findItem(R.id.buy_pro_version)
if(buildConfig.FLAVOR.equalsIgnorCase("paid")){
    //Logic for disabling BuyProVersion Menu item
buyPro.setVisible(false)
}else {
    buyPro.setVisible(true)
}
```

I hope it helps someone someday. 
Make sure you set up productFlavours in your build.gradle