# Setting the text color for a menu item on Smartface (Android)

Tags: smartface.io

I'm struggling to set the menu item text color to white on Android, but without much success.

I've tried:

```
this.actionBar.itemTextColor = "#ffffff"; //this is not working on Android
```

Any ideas? I'm using Smartface 4.3.0

Comment: Below given link give you fully solution ::

   visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for text color change for menu items

```
<style 
 name="myCustomMenuTextApearance"parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
</style>
```