# Change text of android menu item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

My menu layout looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_change_pin"
    android:title="@string/action_change_pin"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I want to change these two items' text color to white from black. How can i do that?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android) out

Comment: I don't understand a bit about themes, I have styles.xml. In which there are a lot of themes, in which one do I have to apply this line: 
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u need to change the style:
try this :

put this in your theme

```
 <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>
```

and in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

should help u out

Comment: Do i need to apply the theme somehow after I write it to my Styles.xml?

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You're my hero! Thank you very much :))))))))))). Have a good day, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme.xml

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/du9sCptC
I added it to the bottom of my styles.xml, but it still doesn't work. Do i have to apply the theme somehow?

Comment: You should apply this theme from android manifest in application tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <style name="ThemeName" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
         <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
         <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/du9sCptC
I added it to the bottom of my styles.xml, but it still doesn't work. Do i have to apply the theme somehow?