# How to change action bar text color?

Tags: android

The text color on my ActionBar and the color of default 3 dot menu have changed to **black** when i migrated my project from eclipse to android studio, i didn't even touch the colors. this could be because of the support library version. anyway how do i change it to white again (not being racist)?

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="red" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here.
            -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionBar text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Comment: Show appbasetheme please

Comment: appbasetheme  was already there when project was created. do you suspect this to be the one changing the color? i dont even know where it came from

Comment: thanks! this was the solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519277/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-menu-item-in-android/29316237#29316237