# Menu Item's Tittle Not Showing

Tags: java, android, menu, android-toolbar, menuitem

Menu item's title is not showing inside fragment. I have two items in menu file, The first one is with icon and tag `showAsAction=always` to show the icon in toolbar. The second one is only with tittle.

I don't know what's going wrong here.

All actions with the menu items is working. E.g below.

[image]

**menu_sale.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="Scanner"
        android:id="@+id/miScanner"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_qr_code_scanner"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

    <item
        android:title="Add Credit Record"
        android:id="@+id/miAddCreditRecord"
        />

</menu>
```

The item without `showAsAction='always'` not showing the title in my app.

My java code to inflate the menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sale, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.miScanner:
            scanCode();
            break;
        case R.id.miAddCreditRecord:
            showBottomSheetDialog();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My theme `theme.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AzmiUnaniStore" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AzmiUnaniStore">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

### POSSIBILITIES

The tittle is showing perfectly but when the action menu colour is white and the background is also white that's is the I am not able to see the tittle.

Thanks

Comment: <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

Comment: @javdromero Before posting the question, I had changed the value of `colorOnPrimary` to a different one to debug the issue. But the issue is same..

Comment: What about the color on the edittexts and the search bar? Is is white also?

Comment: @javdromero The search box is not actually `EditText` it's a `TextView`, When user click on it, I am open another activity.

The EditText which is inside `BottomSheetDialog` is default which is black I think

Comment: `DayNight.DarkActionBar` must be the problem, try to override the color with `<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>` on your theme. Or refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279563/15298643)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the text color in the popup menu.
Add the `app:popupTheme` attribute in your `MaterialToolbar`.

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
        ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary" >
    <!-- text color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>  
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced with same issue. In my case I used custom toolbar with style.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle" />
```

ToolbarStyle

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

So I changed `android:textColorPrimary` in `ToolbarStyle` to black and now it works fine

Comment: I have followed your answer, but the issue is same. see the result -> https://youtu.be/hCuhSkSgzGg

Comment: Please change android:textColorPrimary from white to black

Comment: Working but it's changed all the text color of toolbar like title and icon, etc.
I only want to change the menuItemTextColor.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code to your themes.xml and themes.xml(night) files

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: Make the color black