# Android custom toolbar items not showing

Tags: android

I want to make an app with a custom toolbar with a menu on the toolbar. The problem I have is that when I run the app and I click on the menu on the right side of the toolbar, the options do not appear but the menu box appears. One of the options closes the app and if I click the menu area where the exit option is the app closes.

Here is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="@string/app_name"
    app:logo="@drawable/applogo">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my mainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.exit)
    {
        this.finishAffinity();
    }
    return true;

}
```

}

This is my menu.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:title="@string/new_entry"
    android:id="@+id/add">

</item>

<item
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:id="@+id/about">
</item>

<item
    android:title="@string/exit"
    android:id="@+id/exit">

</item>
```

I created the toolbar xml I set it in MainActivity .. I created the menu xml and I inflate it in MainActivity from all the tutorials these are the steps that I had to go through to get here, yet I don't know why the items in the menu xml file won't show up in the emulator.

Comment: double check the menu text color.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386269/menu-items-tittle-not-showing/67407725#67407725

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thank you.. I didn't find that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to Gabriele Mariotti. In his words: " The issue is the text color in the popup menu." .All I had to do was to was to add the following line of code to the Toolbar xml.

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I have made a demo for you it is working I have tested it on the emulator as well as the device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

my_menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 3"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:title="Item 4"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```