# Menu items are not displayed in the Android app

Tags: android-studio, menu, menuitem, android-theme, android-inflate

everyone! I'm a beginner, developing a mobile app.
Friends, my menu items are not displayed. I click on three dots [clicking on the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SpPX.png). A white window appears [window without menu items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn7tQ.png).
**Program code "menu.xml":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.MAGIC">

    <item
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/search_option"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting_app"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_app" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_app"
        android:title="@string/menu_about_application"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_about" />
</menu>
```

**Program code "themes.xml":**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.MAGIC" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Program code "MainActivity.java"**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem menuItem;
        androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView;

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_option);

        searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

How do I display the menu items? Friends, help solve the problem!
I'm testing the app on a mobile device.

Comment: your menu is showing properly but for changing theme setting your menu text is also showing white instead of black. Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25731668/16765223

Comment: The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the XML file. Added the following line: `<item name="android:textColor">@color/purple_200</item>`. The application menu looks like this:[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwUu4.png)

**Full program code:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- The basic theme of the application -->
<style name="Theme.MAGIC" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- another part of the code -->

    <!-- Text color, including menu text -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/purple_200</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I create my menus, in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` override method I return `true` rather than the `super`.

Also, do you override the `onOptionsItemSelected` method to handle the clicks? You didn't post that code.

Here is Google's documentation on creating menus:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot. Below is the program code.
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.about_app){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutAppActivity.class));
        } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.setting_app){
            showDialogBox();
        }
        return true;
    }