# Change the background of OptionsMenu and add/remove options dynamically

Tags: java, android, user-interface, options-menu

I have used the solution given in post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu) for changing the background of my `OptionsMenu` (over min API 7). But now I have a problem. If after doing it I dynamically add or remove an option the new option comes with correct color but the background of the existing options is reset to the default OS color.

Is possible to avoid that?