# How can we add background Color to the options menu in android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

Options menu has a default color i.e White, I want to change this color to GREEN.
Right now i have tried to add a drawable to my menu item to change its color, but its not working, here is the menu.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

    >

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/character"
        android:id="@+id/icon12"
        android:title="test"

         />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:title="Text"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:title="Icon and Text"
        android:icon="@drawable/item_selector"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/about"
      android:icon="@drawable/action"
      android:title="about"
       /> 
</menu>
```

It does not change the background of the menu item. Any Answers would be appreciated.

I have tried many things, e.g hackandroid etc but nothing seemed to work properly.

Comment: What do you mean by the options menu?

Comment: this is the beautiful blog by Cyril : http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/

Comment: There has been many questions around this, here is a solution that could help. [Menu Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800736/background-of-menuitem-wont-change)

Comment: If you are talking about the actionbar option menu you can use this : http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way) is an artcile that describes customizing the look of the menu that I found useful.