# How can I change an option menu's sub-item selection color programmatically?

Tags: android

I know how to change the selection color of android option menu but how can I change the selection color of an option menu's sub-item?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you're talking about submenus, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu) question might help you (about changing the color of option menus).

Comment: Yeah I know. Couldn't find any attribute that works for subitems only either. The hard way would be to write your own menu from scratch.