# Option menu default gray border removal

Tags: java, android

in my app i have option menu i try to customize it , i did it by refer it to style ,

what i need is either removal of default gray border around option menu or customize it to another color .

any advice will be appreciated .

as shown below :

[image]

My code :

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

   getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
   public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
   AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
try {

  LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

  new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

  view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border1);

  ((TextView) view).setTextSize(20); 

  ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                 }
             });
   return view;  }
   catch (InflateException e) {}
   catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        }
   return null; }
      });
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at this question? [How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu) you should be able to use most of the answers on there to help you!

Comment: i already checked that and many posts related to option menu , but i cant find my target , thanks

Comment: @Blundell yes i do nothing changed .

Comment: @Blundell you are absolutly right , you comment inspirated me that  something wrong in applying (android:panelFullBackground ),so i keep trying till i get it and change it to what i need , really thanks .