# android option menu issue in different versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-version

I have created one simple menu with two options that says "Add new contact" & "Settings" with white png images.

So now if i run in the 2.3.3 android OS version it looks like the below image:

[image: Android 2.3.3 option menu]

now if i run in the 2.2 android os then it looks like the below image:

[image]

So now what can i do if i want to make background black in android 2.2 so that i can get icons visible.
please give me any suggestion regarding this issue.

Comment: You can customize the option menu tab and provide your own background color/image.

Comment: then how can i set the background of the menu?

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu

Comment: Look at this code . http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way

Comment: i also got the solution from this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with option menu is to customize it.

You can customize the option menu, including:

Add a custom font

Change font size

Change font color

Set background to a Drawable resource (e.g. image, border, gradient)

To change background to a border or gradient you have to create a resource folder in res called drawable and, inside it, create the border XML or gradient XML.

This can all be done programatically as shown below:

```
 public class CustomMenu extends Activity {   
/** Called when the activity is first created. */   
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     } 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) { 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();  
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);  
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {  
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, 
                AttributeSet attrs) {   
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(                                             "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) { 
    try {  
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
        final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs); 
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {   
// set the background drawable if you want that or keep it default 
//either FOR image, border, gradient, drawable,etc.//   
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage); 
        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(20);
        // set the text font and color  
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(  
        getAssets(),"OldeEnglish.ttf");  
        ((TextView) view).setTypeface(face); 
        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);      }     }); 
        return view;      } 
        catch (InflateException e) {  
        //Handle any inflation exception here  
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {    
        //Handle any ClassNotFoundException here    
                        }     }   
            return null;    }   }); 
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);     }
```