# Change background popupMenu in Android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-popupwindow

I tried to change background of popupmenu, but my implementation does not work.

This is my code:

```
<style name="MyHoloLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/bgPopumMenu</item>
</style>
```

Apply in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/MyHoloLight">
```

Answer (score 32):

the following styles working perfectly for me.

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/color_red</item>
</style>
```

here, parent should be the **AppTheme** parent

and in your code use these lines.

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
```

i hope it will work.

Comment: This is probably the only answer which works without any hassle. Kudos!

Comment: I spend a lot of days trying to get menu color working. This solution is the only one perfectly working. I'm using AppCompact and MenuPopupHelper. Thanks to @Raju !

Answer (score 7):

If **bgPopumMenu** is your image then use this.

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/bgPopumMenu</item>
</style>
```

You need to apply your style to your AppTheme. So try this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/bgPopumMenu</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is bgPopupMenu is your image or color name??

Comment: bgPopupMenu - this color.

Comment: have you created color xml file for it?

Comment: color created in xml file.

Comment: I tried **bgPopumMenu** use drawable, but this not helped.

Comment: @PiyushGupta it never worked for me. I'm still looking for an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Piyush we should talk in a professional manner with each other at this platform, and this behaviour is expected from everyone, look at the comment of some looser above.

Comment: @AndroidHacker I know but you can talk with him in your personal chat room and you can do whatever you want to tell him

Answer (score 6):

I made some changes of @Raju`s code and the following styles working for me,

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.popupMenuStyle);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, YourView);
```

and this is my style,

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/color_semi_transparent</item>       
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom theme :

1. In Manifest : `@style/MyMaterialTheme` is my customized theme :

   ```
     <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
   ```
2. Use this code : `R.style.popupMenuStyle` for popup menu in java class :

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.popupMenuStyle);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);

//Inflating the Popup using xml file
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

MenuPopupHelper menuHelper = new MenuPopupHelper(wrapper, (MenuBuilder) popup.getMenu(), v);
menuHelper.setForceShowIcon(true);
menuHelper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

3. this is custom style of popup- menu for your own background drawable

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown_bg</item>
</style>
```

4. then change in your own theme "popupMenuStyle"

   ```
   <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

       </style>

       <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
           <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
           <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>

           <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
           <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
       </style>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I SOLVED it,

`PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);`

In above code I used context of type `Activity` not of `Context` type.

Chill !

Answer (score 0):

what about this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    setMenuBackground(); 
    return true;    
}
```

and write this in the `setMenuBackground()` method

```
protected void setMenuBackground(){                              
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory( new Factory() {  
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" ) ) {
                    try { // Ask our inflater to create the view  
                        LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();  
                        final View view = f.createView( name, null, attrs );  
                        /* The background gets refreshed each time a new item is added the options menu.  
                        * So each time Android applies the default background we need to set our own  
                        * background. This is done using a thread giving the background change as runnable 
                        * object */
                        new Handler().post( new Runnable() {  
                            public void run () {  
                                // sets the background here
                                view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.bgPopumMenu);
                                // sets the text color              
                                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                // sets the text size              
                                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(18);
                }
                        } );  
                    return view;
                }
            catch ( InflateException e ) {}
            catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {}  
        } 
        return null;
    }}); 
}
```

Comment: Error will occur: *A factory has already been set on this LayoutInflater*

Comment: because of a small change on the support library, see this link for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415284/java-lang-illegalstateexception-a-factory-has-already-been-set-on-this-layoutin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give `android:popupBackground` as just a color. You should use or create a `drawable`.

You can use this link http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ to generate your desired color. And set it to that `drawable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` in your theme:

```
<style name="MyHoloLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>
</style>
<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/bgPopumMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@color/bgPopumMenu_whenSelected</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If bgPopumMenu is your drawable then use this

```
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@drawable/bgPopumMenu</item>
```

You just put that directly into your AppTheme like so

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@drawable/bgPopumMenu</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a style for popup menu and apply that style to a theme and you  can assign the theme to the Activity/Parent Activity*** in the android manifest like this

```
<style name="MyThemePopup" parent="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

Create @style/PopupMenu like this

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Assign the MyThemePopup theme to your Activity/Parent Activity*** in AndroidManifest as

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyThemePopup"/>
```

***When you using the fragment apply the theme for the parent activity defined in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

just add below line into Style.xml and its working :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- To change action bar menuItem BG -->
            <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: This will change only an item's background not the whole menus background, so after doing this there'll be still some different colour margins left on top and bottom.

Comment: You have to remove margin and it is working on popup-menu for all the item's background color will change.. also your app must use parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" this actionbar..