# Android: how to change background color in popupmenu

Tags: android, styles, popupmenu

I'm trying to change the color of PopMenu that is displayed by a onlongclick method. I used the following style but had no effect, are there any suggestions on how I can change the style of PopMenu? The style was declared in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<style name="NewStyle" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PoppupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PoppupMenu" parent="android:Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/corazul</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change background popupMenu in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320663/change-background-popupmenu-in-android)

Comment: made attempts to further questions and no results.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer then accept it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved the problem using this code:

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.PopupMenu);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
```

reference: [blog.stylingandroid.com](http://blog.stylingandroid.com)

Comment: This solved my problem, but I used the "android:itemBackground" attribute instead of "android:popupBackground" in my style definition