# How to create the Android Custom Popup Menu

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I'm developing android app the app required the custom popup menu it should work on Version 2.1 to 5, The popup look like please Refer the line [please click the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306100/custom-popupmenu-layout)

Comment: ListPopUpWindow is part of the compatibility library.

Comment: can you tell me the compatibility library name ?

Comment: android support library

Comment: I'm already having the appcompact-v7 lib also the app working on the Android lollipop theme.

Comment: `import android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow;`

Comment: can you show the some sample example or link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android also has a default support for that in support v7 android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow , however if you need a tutorial you can find it [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/styling-the-actionbar-part-3/)

You can use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) Library for [ListPopWindow](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/src/org/holoeverywhere/widget/ListPopupWindow.java) it starts from sdk version 7 and up