# Android menu inflating in the wrong place

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, menuitem

Here is my current problem:

My settings menu is inflating incorrectly. I have no idea why, and it is driving me nuts! Does anyone have a clue as to what is happening? The position of the menu should be slightly under the overflow icon. Is it perhaps the way I laid out my tabs or viewpagers, or is it something else? I'm sure this is not an isolated case, so if anyone has seen this problem before...

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

In my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In my menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/menu_item">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is default UI pattern and is not incorrect, refer following screenshot from [official documentation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#):
[image]

still if you don't like it, you can change this behaviour

refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834089/anchor-popup-menu-over-overflow-button/28955735#28955735) for details.