# How to show PopupWindow above keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to show a `PopupWindow` above virtual keyboard like Google Keep did when creating a reminder:

[image]

Comment: i think you will find this helpful https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment

Comment: @RachelGallen But I want to show it at any location on screen...

Answer (score 13):

I believe, what you are looking for is combination of:

```
popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
```

It's basically how native **SearchView** works:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-6.0.1_r31/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#1695
which basically calls **AutocompleteTextView.ensureImeVisible()**

```
public void ensureImeVisible(boolean visible) {
    mPopup.setInputMethodMode(visible
            ? ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED : ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED);
    if (mPopup.isDropDownAlwaysVisible() || (mFilter != null && enoughToFilter())) {
        showDropDown();
    }
}
```

This would resize Popup window to be shown exactly between Anchor and Keyboard.

Comment: this solved another problem i wanted to solve, which was to let keyboard ABOVE my popup :) just used .setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED)

Answer (score 0):

use the following code. Change the location of the popup window in the method "showAtLocation".

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null, false), ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
    findViewById(R.id.activity_layout).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.activity_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); //set location here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) display above (on top of, or in front of) the on-screen keyboard, and make it dismiss when clicked outside, use this:

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(context);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED);
```

Sample code: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

---

To make a [`ListPopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow) display in front of the keyboard, and make it automatically close when clicked outside, use this:

```
listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(context);
listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
listPopupWindow.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED);
```

Sample code: [Custom PopupMenu (layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306100/custom-popupmenu-layout)