# onbackpressed not called when ListPopupWindow is showing in android. also user is not able to touch outside of the ListPopupWindow to dismiss

Tags: android, popupwindow, onbackpressed, android-popupwindow

[about ListPopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow)

**ListPopupWindow** is different than **PopupWindow**. i have tried all the solution to dismiss the showing window. i have tried .dismiss but it is not dismiss first time when user click second time then only it is dismissed.

also **ListPopupWindow** not support `setCancelable(true)` or `setOutsideTouchable(false)` like method to dismiss window when user touch on outside of the window. or press back button.

Comment: Hi Nikul ,please share you code

Comment: hello, @Avinashtiwari  i have used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191914/10573140). difference between this link and on my code is only that i'm used image to the right side of the text item. and i want image to the right side of the text. that's why i'm used **ListPopupWindow** otherwise i knew we can set image using this code `<item        android:icon="@drawable/msg_count_dot"` in **PopupMenu**

Answer (score 0):

try `popupWindow.setModal(true)`.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#setModal(boolean)