# Styling Android PopupMenu Divider Lines

Tags: android, android-layout, customization, divider, android-popupwindow

I'm using a couple of `PopupMenu`s in my app and they all working as expected

[image: Menu image]

But I would like to have white lines separating the individual items, but I can't find where I'm meant to be setting this. I was hoping I could get to the underlying ListView but that doesn't seem to be possible. I can't see an style item that relates to the divider line either.

Is this possible, where/how should I be setting this?

Comment: Does this help @flexicoder? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu

Comment: @garfbradaz no thats the text not the divider line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been able to update the divider colour on a PopupMenu using the following technique (based on clues from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40017199/285190)

Create a style as follows...

```
<style name="popupMenuStyle" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#eaeaea</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Then when you create the menu create a context wrapper

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, sourceView);
```

This does show a dividing line, BUT the height of the menu doesn't appear to be calculated correctly to include the new divider and a vertical scrollbar is displayed.

If anyone knows the reason please add a comment

Comment: Hey @Flexicoder can you try adding the divider and dividerHeight as below: 

    `<style name="popupMenuStyle" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDown.Theme</item>
</style>

    <style name="DropDown.Theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:divider">@color/your_color</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    </style>`

I could get rid of the vertical scroll bars this way.

Comment: why it is not working for me on Android 6.0.  Only thing works for me is setting the textColor and background but divider does not show up...

Comment: per our UX I have to use White for background and unfortunately, divider also uses white background.  when I change the menu background to any other color I see the divider but not when it is white...  So, how do I change the divider color?  <item name="android:divider">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item> does not work....

Comment: @Vincy - sounds like you need to ask a new question

Comment: @pablogeorge's answer solved it for me. Thanks a lot to both!

Answer (score 2):

this is how I achieved it.  colorBankground is to change the color of the line divider.

```
    <style name="PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/background_medium_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/BackgroundGray</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>

    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.PopupMenu);
    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);

    final MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
```

Comment: I wonder if you'd know how to set the divider width, like 80 percent of the total menu width;