# custom popup menu background not working for Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar android

Tags: android, popup

i have made a `popup menu`. now i want to customize its background color. i have followed some tutorial and stackoverflow but nothing working. app base theme is

**Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**

```
my style code is:
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/OptionMenu</item>-->
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#167be1</item>
</style>

<!--<style name="OptionMenu" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">-->

    <!--<item name="android:popupBackground">#1278ce</item>-->

<!--</style>-->
```

can anyone please help me on this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671629/change-popup-menu-background-color

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=custom+popup+menu+background+not+working+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=EyC&channel=fs&dcr=0&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSlM2NqpHaAhVLr48KHb8qAIEQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1600&bih=727

Comment: maybe same, infact i have tried with same solution but not working @NileshRathod

Comment: okay wait, i will let you know if it works or not

Comment: thanks its working now :). but why did not work the way i had done with? @NileshRathod

Comment: yes please. and one more thing how to add margin to menu items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<style name="OptionMenu" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:itemBackground">#21B6D7</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>
```

apply theme to your **`PopupMenu`** like this

```
Context contextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.OptionMenu);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(contextWrapper, v);
```

Comment: no. this way :

<style name="OptionMenu" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:popupBackground">#1278ce</item>

</style>

Comment: tried already but not working and Gravity.end is for api 24 maybe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694486/styling-android-popupmenu-divider-lines This one worked :)

Comment: @AAA grate enjoy codding