# Android View Pager IllegalStateException: A factory has already been set on this LayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, illegalstateexception

I want to do a 4-screen tutorial for my app, but I'm getting this exception when I try to start the Activity that contains the ViewPager:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A factory has already been set on this LayoutInflater
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.setFactory2(LayoutInflater.java:297)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.setFactory2(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:96)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC.setFactory(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:51)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat$LayoutInflaterCompatImplV11.setFactory(LayoutInflaterCompat.java:42)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(LayoutInflaterCompat.java:79)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:936)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1072)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:918)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1440)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1920)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1117)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5692)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:515
```

At first I followed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) , but the sample app doesn't use support library. Than I tried to follow [this one](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/) and still got the exception. Both samples run ok in my phone, can't figure out why is not working in my project

Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.app.Tutorial.TutorialActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TutorialActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class TutorialActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new TutorialPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

}
```

Adapter:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TutorialPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public TutorialPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TutorialFragment myFragment = new TutorialFragment();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("page", position);
    myFragment.setArguments(data);
    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class TutorialFragment extends Fragment {
private int mPageNumber;
public static TutorialFragment create(int pageNumber) {
    TutorialFragment fragment = new TutorialFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page", pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt("page");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false);
}

}
```

SDK is up-to-date, I'm targeting sdk 22, min version is 9... [Other SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415284/java-lang-illegalstateexception-a-factory-has-already-been-set-on-this-layoutin) are about using `getLayoutInflater().setFactory()`, but I'm not using it anywhere. Any hint on this? Thanks!

[EDIT] I'm using `com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1`, while the work sample uses `com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and this problem is related to Calligraphy Library.
Just use the latest Calligraphy Library by checking in your build.gradle file :

```
  compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
```