# How to set a typeface to menu items in overflow menu on toolbar

Tags: android, android-menu, layout-inflater, android-inflate, android-typeface

I want to change the default typeface of the items of the **overflow menu and set a custom typeface**.

I tried adding a Factory to the `LayoutInflater` and within the `onCreateView()` method I changed the **TextView's typeface**. But it didn't work. Here is the code(Inside onCreateOptionsMenu),

```
getLayoutInflater().cloneInContext(this).setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

            if (name.contains("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                try {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((TextView) view).setTypeface("custom_typeface");
                        }
                    });
                    return view;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Actually when I debug the code, it never reached inside onCreateView().

So how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: well, it should be obvious ... you cloned it and set factory ... but never use it  ...

Comment: @Selvin can you explain more..

Comment: read documentation of cloneInContext - it creates copy ... and ... with minimal logical thinking you should know that you never use this copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue,

step 1: create a global Factory variable and initialized in onCreate() like below,

```
  mFactory = new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                try {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTypeface("custom_typeface");
                        }
                    });

                    return view;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Step 2: override the **onCreateView() method in AppCompatActivity**.
remember there are 2 oncreate() methods with different signatures.

public View onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) - for pre HONEYCOMB apps

public View onCreateView (View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) - added in API 11.

The implementation of onCreateView is like below,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    if(name.contains("android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView")) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = null;
        try {
            view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (view != null) {
            if(mFactory != null) {
                view = mFactory.onCreateView(name,context,attrs);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}
```

**Note:**

(1) I used [android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.java) instead of [com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/IconMenuItemView.java) since I am using the AppCompat support library.

(2) Since I have already initialized a Factory object in onCreate(), I removed the code segment(posted in my question) from onCreateOptionsMenu(). So it contains only this part,

```
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu); 
 return true;
```

References :

[How to set a font for the Options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376591/1134412)

[Android Menu item font using LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319161/android-menu-item-font-using-layoutinflatercompat-setfactory)