# Disable ActionBar Menu Item but still clickable

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I would like to disable the `ActionBar Menu Item` but make it clickable. Is there any way I can do this?

Right now, it's just greyed out if I set `setEnabled` as `false` which is normal behavior but it's not clickable.

Comment: what do you mean greyed out but not `clickable`. If you call `setEnabled(false)` it will be greyed out.

Comment: Yes, I want it greyed out but I also want it to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question as the `ActionBar Menu Item` cannot be disabled and clickable at the same time. What I ended up doing was enabling the `Menu Item` and setting the text color to grey to make it look pseudo-disabled. And if the condition was fulfilled it would change to default color.

Credit: [Nicolai Buch Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14554438/100747)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    text.append(getString(R.string.menu_title));

    if (someCondition){
         text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 
                 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    else {
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.LTGRAY), 
                0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }


    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.some_menu_id);
    item.setTitle(text);

    return true;
}
```