# Options menu item pressed background

Tags: android, android-menu, android-styles, android-optionsmenu

I styled my action bar with [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), so when i press an action drop down item, the background color changes to a custom color instead of the default. Now i want to implement this behavior in the old options menu, too. I tried everything from [this answer collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475357/747412), unfortunately none of them worked. How can i achieve this on the options menu? Note that i'm using ActionbarSherlock and HoloEverywhere, but i think this does not matter here, because these uses the native implementation for the options menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved the issue.
I generated a theme for `List Selector` with the [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/).
I applied the theme. The option menu style also changed on API 11+, because it uses `List Selector` to theme the options menu dropdown list.
I still cannot properly style the options menu on API 10 and below, but at least my application theme is consistent from API 11.