# Android actionbar option menu color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to change the action bar option menu color?

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
        bar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0f260d'>Counter </font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You always can use this: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

And see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475357/3864698