# How to set a background image or color or gradient for menu items in android action bar

Tags: android, menu, background, gradient, menuitem

[image]

I would like to set the background image as shown for the menus by using Appcompat theme. Please let me know the example and attribute.

Comment: Please check the attached image.

Comment: fortunately you cannot do that

Answer (score -1):

Check this answer - [Change the background color of the options menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu)

I doubt I can explain it better than that.