# How to toggle menu icon on the app bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Erm instead of using toggle button can I toggle icon in app bar instead?

like when I pressed my icon in the app bar it will change to other icon

Here is my menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="course.examples.healthcare_application.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <!--lower value will be on the left-->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Bluetooth_connect"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/bluetooth_connect" />
</menu>
```

Code on main activity

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        if(id == R.id.Bluetooth_connect){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @2Dee how do I unblock this? Why is it on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define them in a selector like this in your drawable folder:

button_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/initialpressed"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/on"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/initial"/>
</selector>
```

Then define it in your button like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_state"
```

Comment: Hi. erm I need to create a new file in a drawable folder? I don't quite get you. Actually I am not using button. I using icon in the menu folder

Comment: Okay . you just try a simple tutorial http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html#.VovwU9IdAlI

Comment: erm what I want is the icon on the app bar and not on the windowbackground

Comment: please show me your onclicklistener

Comment: Hi. I uploaded the main activity code. I not using the onclicker. I am using the onOptionMenuselected.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8475357/4919237

Comment: check this example too http://hmkcode.com/android-menu-handling-click-events-changing-menu-items-at-runtime/

Comment: The second tutorial link worked! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the toggle effect, you could change the color of the button when it is clicked. If the icon is a drawable, the color can be set with the tint attribute.

In xml the tint can be set with

```
android:tint="@color/icon_pressed"
```

In code the tint can be set with

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```